# Finding series solution of xy'' + y = 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I do not know how to format equations on here, so here is a picture of my attempt: [image]

Why is it that when trying to find the coefficients about the indicial root r=0 leads to undefined coefficients? The textbook claims both roots r = 1 and 0 have the same series solution? Unfortunately the textbook does not show the derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you get the first equations
$$
0=r(r-1)c_0\\
-c_0=(r+1)rc_1\\
-c_1=(r+2)(r+1)c_2
$$
etc. In the case $r=0$ the second equation tells you that $c_0=0$ and $c_1$ is arbitrary and determines the other coefficients,
$$
y_0(x)=c_1(x-\frac12x^2\pm\dots).
$$
 In the case $r=1$ you get a solution based on $c_0$, but now with additional factor $x=x^r$ so that
$$
y_1(x)=c_0x(1-\frac12x+\frac1{12}x^2\mp\dots)
$$
which in the end is the same solution. You get the second basis solution by order reduction, set $y_2(x)=u(x)y_0(x)$ where $c_1=1$ with the equation
$$
0=x(u''y_0+2u'y_0')\implies u'(x)=y_0(x)^{-2}=x^{-2}\left(1 + x + \frac{7}{12}x^2 + \frac{19}{72}x^3 + \frac{149}{1440}x^4 + \dots\right)
\\
\implies u(x)=-\frac1x+\ln(x)+\frac{7}{12}x + \frac{19}{144}x^2 + \frac{149}{4320}x^3 + \dots
$$
which gives the solution that is singular in $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused there for a second because of the method the textbook was using in a previous example where they used a recurrence relationship.

Comment: All the following coefficients are computed via that recurrence. It is only the first two coefficients where it gets somewhat knotty. It should come out as $$y_0(x)=x\left(1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}{k!(k+1)!}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the indicial equation, write the ODE as,
$$ x^2 y'' + (x) y' + 0 = 0 $$
From this form, $b(x) = x$ and $c(x) = 0$, giving
$$ r(r-1) + b_0 r + c_0 = r^2 - r + r = r(r - 1) = 0 $$
$$ r_1 = 1,\ r_2 = 0 $$
Using the larger root $r_1$,
$$ y_1             = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_{m}\ x^{m+1} = 
 \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{m-1}\ x^{m}      $$
$$ xy_1''         = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{m}\ m(m+1) x^{m}  $$
$$ a_{m}          = \frac{-a_{m-1}}{(m)(m+1)}                $$
$$ y_1             = x\left[ 1 - \frac{x}{2!}
                  + \frac{x^2}{2 \cdot 3!} - \frac{x^3}{6 \cdot 4!}
              + \dots\right] = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}
\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!\ m!}\ x^{m}                         $$
Since the two roots of the indicial equation differ by an integer,
there exists a second root of the form,
$$ y_2     = ky_1\ln(x) + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}A_m x^m $$
$$ y_2''   = k\left[y_1'' \ln(x) - \frac{y_1}{x^2}
              + \frac{2y_1'}{x}\right] + \sum_{m=2}^{\infty} A_m\ m(m-1) x^{m-2} $$
Skipping the steps to find $y_1'$ and $y_1/x$, and consolidating terms,
and noting that the term in square brackets is zero,
$$ xy_2'' + y_2 = 0 = k\ln(x)\ [xy_1'' + y_1] - \frac{ky_1}{x} + 2ky_1'  + 1 + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\{A_m + A_{m+1}\ m(m+1)\} x^m   $$
$$ -(k+1)   = k \left[\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m (2m + 1)}
                  {m!\ (m+1)!}\ x^m\right]
              + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}[A_m + A_{m+1}\ m(m+1)] x^m $$
Since the LHS contains all of the $x^0$ terms,
$$ k = -1 $$
Using this value of $k$ in the RHS, and matching the coefficients of $x^1$ onwards, and setting $A_0 = 1$ by convention,
$$ A_{m+1} = \left[ \frac{(-1)^{m} (2m+1)}{m!\ (m+1)!} - A_m \right]
              \ \frac{1}{m(m+1)}   $$
This generates the series,
$$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} A_m x^m = x - \frac{5}{4}x^2 + \frac{5}{18}x^3 
+ \dots $$
The second lineraly independent solution with a singular point at $x = 0$ is
therefore,
$$ y_2(x) = -\ln(x)\ y_1(x) + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} A_m x^m$$
where the coefficients $\{A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots\}$ are found using the above recursive relation.

The alternative approach is to use reduction of order, but that is not as easy to follow.

Comment: This answer assumes no knowledge of Bessel's functions or any special functions. WolframAlpha for example, can be used to cross check the first solution by asking it to provide a series expansion of the Bessel function answer that its ODE solver spits out.